# Measuring radon level

Tags: radiation, measurements

In theory what are the techniques used to measure the levels of radon in air?

On which principle/law do they rely?

Comment: http://www.epa.gov/radon/pdfs/homes_protocols.pdf and many other easily Googlable articles. They work by measuring the radioactivity from decaing radon nuclei.

Comment: @JohnRennie actually almost all the questions on this site are easily googlable I was just looking for a basic brief summary, anyway thanks for the font, I will read it.

Comment: Most of the *good* question on this site are *not* easily searchable. Or they weren't until they were asked he. That's kind of the point.

Comment: @dmckee maybe this is not a good question if it makes you happy. However after *an easy Google search* I found anything about this topic because I simply didn't know what to search. So I don't think that asking is a sin.

Answer (score 1):

Three simple solutions suggest (looking at beta-decay):

1) Get a nice (solid state) Geiger counter with a sensitive pancake detector.  Get a baseline reading outside mid-afternoon, then one inside. The difference is radon.  (Do a field survey of the area.  Wallboard's gypsum can be superphosphate manufacturing waste.  It concentrates actinides and decay daughters.  Granite (including concrete aggregate) can be amazingly hot.  Civilian water softener resins may have started as nuclear power plant last loop polishing resin beds.  Crickets!)

2) Leave a CRT TV on overnight, swab the screen with a tissue damp with rubbing alcohol, put under a Geiger Counter.  Electrostatic scrubbing of airborne radon charged decay daughters is surprisingly good.

3) Suck a whole lot of air through an activated carbon cartridge, break it open, and count that.

These make interesting high school science projects, especially when parents panic afterwards.  Are you feeling clean and wholesome?  Science has the cure.

Answer (score 0):

As usual, Uncle Al comes through with some really interesting answers that sound like a lot of fun to try for science projects.  Glass CRTs are getting very hard to come by these days, however.  Some of the Oreck electrostatic air cleaners should work in its place. Simply swab dust off of the inside of the Truman cell after sufficient dust collects there.  Be careful not to damage the corona wires, which are on the front side of the Truman cell.

For a typical consumer, the activated charcoal radon absorbers will theoretically do an adequate job, but a very low cfm (cubic feet per minute) fan directed at the canister while it is open (typically for 1 hour) probably wouldn't hurt. Lower speed fans used for cooling cpus should work as well as a professional monitoring setup.  The labs that process these canisters have sensitive equipment that most consumers would probably not wish to worry about building or playing with.

When exposing the radon collecting canisters, be sure and place them as near as possible to any large exposed areas concrete slab on the first floor or basement areas without a lot of outside ventilation.  These are the areas likely to have a buildup of radon gas if your home is located in an area where this could be a problem.